# How to match all character before the first whitespace using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

I'd like to use grep to match all characters before the first whitespace.

```
grep "^[^\s]*" filename.txt
```

did not work. Instead, all characters before the first `s` are matched. Is there no `\s` available in grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try with perl regex flag `P` and `o` flag to show only matched part in the output:

```
grep -oP "^\S+" filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With a POSIX character class:

```
grep -o '^[^[:blank:]]*' filename.txt
```

As for where `\s` is available:

- [POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) supports only Basic Regular Expressions or, when called `grep -E`, Extended Regular Expressions, both of which have no `\s`
- [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) supports `\s` as a synonym for `[[:space:]]`
- [BSD grep](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&sektion=&n=1) doesn't seem to support `\s`

Alternatively, you could use awk with the field separator explicitly set to a single space so leading blanks aren't ignored:

```
awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }'
```